# Unzip folder and upload all files to Google cloud

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I want to unzip a folder and upload all its files and folders to Google Cloud using PHP API.
I am unable to find any google cloud function for this action .

Help me Please

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the gzip functionality and push the entire zip at once, like described on https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/transcoding

Or you could unzip it on your own server and upload each file individually. But the first method seems to be preferable in my opinion.

Comment: then please tell me how to upload all files and folders with PHP scanedir()